# Supertest returns 301 using express app. App only takes hosted server

Tags: javascript, express, testing, supertest

Hi I am using supertest to test my Node js express server application.

Here is what I am trying to achieve.

```
let request = require('supertest');
let app = require('./server.js');

request(app).get("/api").then(data=>{//*do something here*//});
```

However, I am getting `301 Moved Permanently`

If I actually start my server on port 8008, then change test to

```
let request = require('supertest');
let app = require('./server.js');
let agent = request.agent('localhost:8008');

agent.get("/api").then(data=>{//*do something here*//});
```

Then I get correct api responses as I expect.

Is there a way to make it work and get 200 response by using `request(app)` instead of using `localhost:8008`?

I will be running tests as part of continuous integration and I don't have full control of testing environment that I won't be able to run testing server each to have access to localhost.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that it was issue with SSL connection that I was enforcing on express.

I have conditionally turned off SSL enforcement on testing environment, and it works as I expected!

Hope this helps anyone who have same issue in the future :)

Comment: You can mark your answer accepted if it solved the issue you mentioned in the question, which it seemingly does. Thanks.